# Pipe find results into grep producing no results

Tags: grep, find, pipe

Simple question here. `find -L . -path "*/lef/*.lef" | grep MACRO` produces no results. However, `find -L . -path "*/lef/*.lef"` gives results and running `grep MACRO` on one of the results returns matches. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the commands you use for the second method?

Comment: Sure. `find -L . -path "*/lef/*.lef"` matches 3 files in the current directory:
`./lef/sc9mcpp84_14lpp_custom_hvt_c16.lef` and similar names.
`grep MACRO ./lef/sc9mcpp84_14lpp_custom_hvt_c16.lef` produces many results.

Comment: `find` gives you file names, but your grep commands looks at file contents. You want `find -exec grep`, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` returns a list of file names. You pipe this list to `grep`, so what you actually do is to check if

```
./lef/sc9mcpp84_14lpp_custom_hvt_c16.lef
./lef/sc9mcpp84_14lpp_custom_hvt_c17.lef
./lef/sc9mcpp84_14lpp_custom_hvt_c18.lef
```

(or whatever `find` returns) contains the string `MACRO`. It doesn't, so you don't get results.

`grep MACRO ./lef/sc9mcpp84_14lpp_custom_hvt_c16.lef`, on the other hand, checks if `MACRO` is found *in* the file. The make `grep` look at the file contents instead of file names, you could either use `xargs`:

```
find -L . -path "*/lef/*.lef" | xargs grep MACRO
```

or you can tell `find` that you want to do something with its results:

```
find -L . -path "*/lef/*.lef" -exec grep MACRO {} \+
```

If you want to use `xargs` and make sure weird file names (containing spaces) are dealt with correctly, you could use `-print0`

```
find -L . -path "*/lef/*.lef" -print0 | xargs -0 grep MACRO
```

which separates file names by a null character instead of a newline character; the `-0` option tells `xargs` about it.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still confused about piping it to grep. It looks like `grep` cannot handle a list of files as an argument, which is what `find` is piping. I guess that would make sense, and so it would treat that data as `stdin`.

That's confusing because I don't see any mention in the grep man page about that, but for some reason using *.lef would work.

Comment: grep behaves differently if a file name is *piped* to it (tries to match the pattern with the file *name*) or if it gets a file name as an *argument* (tries to match the pattern with the file *content*). `xargs` turns a piped file name into an argument, that's why it works.